# VSFTPD does not work correctly

Tags: linux, ftp

i want to access all files of my linux server from my windows computer with ftp. The problem is, with my normal account i cant edit or upload files outside the home/user folder.

My config:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES

anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES

local_root=/
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
write_enable=YES

dirmessage_enable=YES

use_localtime=YES

xferlog_enable=YES

connect_from_port_20=YES

chroot_local_user=YES

secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/certs/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
```

EDIT: If i try to delete a folder or a file i get this error:

```
550 Remove directory operation failed.
```

Comment: That's normal and expected.

Comment: @MichaelHampton and how can I access all files and folders on my server? before i reset my server this was the case without any changes to the config so i am confused

Comment: Log in as root?

Comment: I cant log in as root via ftp. it says wrong password. but i can log in via ssh or console

Comment: Why aren't you using ssh?!

Comment: Maybe to transfer files???? I want to drag and drop them. It is so easier

Comment: So you can use SFTP. There is no reason to have an FTP server.

Comment: Can i also drag and drop files there or is it only shell?

Comment: That depends on what program you used. FileZilla can do it.

Answer (score -1):

SOLUTION:
For everybody who has the same problem in the future:

With my user i've done:

```
sudo chmod 777 /
```

Now i have the permission to edit all files from the server.

Comment: And so does everyone else. Now you have trashed your system and will probably have to reinstall it.